# Get 5 tables data in one query ... no joins ... no relations

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 5 tables or more for a logs.

> 1. tbl_product_log
> 2. tbl_user_log
> 3. tbl_customer_log
> 4. tbl_vendor_log
> 5. tbl_quotations_logs

They have no relation with each other. But they have same hierarchy of columns.

> 1. logid
> 2. logdetails
> 3. logdatetime

Every time when, there is something happened in these tables (e.g. 'insert','delete',update) a record inserted in relative table for a log.

Now I want to show all logs in one page. There are 6 tabs in it.

> 1. All Logs
> 2. Product Logs
> 3. User Logs
> 4. Customer Logs
> 5. Vendor Logs
> 6. Quotation Logs

Like this

[image]

In Every tab e.g. `(products logs, user logs, customer logs ....)` I get all there log data successfully.

[image]

[image]

Now I want to show all logs data in `All` tab like in other tabs.

I tried query by my own but it shows me every thing separately.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product_log, tbl_user_log, tbl_customer_log, tbl_vendor_log, tbl_quotations_logs Limit 20
```

And here is result

[image]

So please tell me how can I achieve this, that all logs data show in `All tab` only in three columns like other tabs show the result with one query.

Hop you understand my question.

Comment: Since you already fetch each single table it would be maybe better to merge them with php. This saves you an additional select union statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use union to connect all tables

```
(Select * From tbl_product_log LIMIT 5)

union

(Select * From tbl_user_log LIMIT 5)

union

(Select * From tbl_customer_log LIMIT 5)

union

(Select * From tbl_vendor_log LIMIT 5)

union

(Select * From tbl_quotation_log LIMIT 5);
```

notes : this query will produce a total of 25 records

Comment: it is working perfectly ... just one more thing ... please tell me how can i apply `Limit` clause because it gives me 1500+ data

Comment: how record do you want in one 'All' page?

Comment: I told you your query working perfectly ... just tel me how can i apply limit clause

Comment: There is possibility some records could be duplicated. Such a query would select just distinct values. Use `UNION ALL` to select all (i.e. even duplicated records). Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp).

Comment: @deemi What is exact query, what is exact error, do all tables contain exact the same fields?

Comment: @deemi I've edited my answer, that query will produce a total of 25 records

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '1' as identifier 
FROM tbl_product_log 
UNION ALL 
SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '2' as identifier FROM tbl_user_log 
UNION ALL 
SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '3' as identifier FROM tbl_customer_log 
UNION ALL 
SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '4' as identifier FROM tbl_vendor_log 
UNION ALL 
SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '5' as identifier FROM tbl_quotations_logs ) as a 
-- WHERE indentifier = '' -- in here you can put here to filter what report you wanted to appear 
ORDER BY logid -- Order it by Logid 
LIMIT 20 -- change the limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UNION instead

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '1' as identifier FROM tbl_product_log) as a
UNION ALL
(SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '2' as identifier FROM tbl_user_log) as b
UNION ALL
(SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '3' as identifier FROM tbl_customer_log) as c
UNION ALL
(SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '4' as identifier FROM tbl_vendor_log) as d
UNION ALL
(SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '5' as identifier FROM tbl_quotations_logs) as e
-- WHERE indentifier = '' //in here you can put here to filter what report you wanted to appear
ORDER BY logid // Order it by Logid
LIMIT 20 //change the limit
```

Put an identifier on each table you combine with other so you still have a control where that data came from.

Comment: bro your qury give me alot of errors 

`Error
Static analysis:
8 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 187)
    Unexpected token. (near "b" at position 190)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 284)
    Unexpected token. (near "c" at position 287)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 379)
    Unexpected token. (near "d" at position 382)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 479)
    Unexpected token. (near "e" at position 482)`

Comment: `SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM (SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '1' as identifier FROM tbl_product_log) as a UNION ALL (SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '2' as identifier FROM tbl_user_log) as b UNION ALL (SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '3' as identifier FROM tbl_customer_log) as c UNION ALL (SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '4' as identifier FROM tbl_vendor_log) as d UNION ALL (SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '5' as identifier FROM tbl_quotations_logs) as e ORDER BY logid LIMIT 20`

Comment: `MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as b
UNION ALL
(SELECT logid, logdetails,logdatetime, '3' as identifier FROM t' at line 4`

Comment: Give me a tested query please

Comment: can I have your sample SQL so I can check